# ConcurrentMap is not concurrent? Can't remove a node from check-alive-system

Tags: java, concurrency, cluster-computing, isalive

I'm trying to have concurrency on a thread in my check-"AliveSystem" which is on every node in the cluster for sending alive-packets and checking if another node sent his alive-packet under the given time with max. 3 fails.

`gotAlive()` is executed outside when got an alive-packet

`addNode()` or `removeNode()` are executed when another node logs in/out

But when e.g. `removeNode()` is executed, so that `getNodes().isEmpty()` should be true because there are 100%ly no other nodes, then `getNodes().isEmpty()` still false

Maybe for better understanding, here is an example:

1. node1 start
2. enable AliveSystem (on node1)
3. node2 start
4. enable AliveSystem (on node2)
5. `addNode(node1)` (on node2)
6. `addNode(node2)` (on node1)
7. stop node1
8. `removeNode(node1)` (on node2)
9. AliveSystem still check for node1 (on node2)

The AliveSystem class:

```java
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import net.mypvp.cloud.cluster.packets.NodeAlivePacket;
import net.mypvp.core.network.redwork.RedworkManager;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

@Log4j2
public class AliveSystem implements Closeable {
    
    // Period in millis for sending/receiving alive packets
    private static final long DEFAULT_ALIVE_PERIOD = 2000L;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CHECK_ALIVE_FAILS = 3;
    
    
    private final String CHANNEL_TOPIC;
    private final long ALIVE_PERIOD;
    private final int CHECK_ALIVE_FAILS;
    
    private final ScheduledExecutorService SEND_NODE_ALIVE_SCHEDULER;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService CHECK_NODES_ALIVE_SCHEDULER;
    
    // Map<Node, last alive-packet millis>>
    private final Map<Node, Long> ALIVE_PACKETS = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
    // Map<Node, Fails counter>
    private final Map<Node, Integer> FAILS = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
    
    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param channelTopic      where to send the keep-alive-packets to
     * @param nodeDeathConsumer consumer executed on node death
     */
    AliveSystem( String channelTopic, Consumer<Node> nodeDeathConsumer ) {
        this( channelTopic, DEFAULT_ALIVE_PERIOD, DEFAULT_CHECK_ALIVE_FAILS, nodeDeathConsumer );
    }
    
    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param channelTopic      where to send the keep-alive-packets to
     * @param alivePeriod       period to send new keep-alive-packet
     * @param checkAliveFails   number of fails before node death
     * @param nodeDeathConsumer consumer executed on node death
     */
    AliveSystem( String channelTopic, long alivePeriod, int checkAliveFails, Consumer<Node> nodeDeathConsumer ) {
        CHANNEL_TOPIC = channelTopic;
        ALIVE_PERIOD = alivePeriod;
        CHECK_ALIVE_FAILS = checkAliveFails;
        
        // Send node alive scheduler.
        SEND_NODE_ALIVE_SCHEDULER = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool( 5 );
        SEND_NODE_ALIVE_SCHEDULER.scheduleAtFixedRate( ( ) -> {
            if ( getClusterManager().isNodeLoggedIn() && !getNodes().isEmpty() )
                getRedwork().sendPacketAsync( new NodeAlivePacket(), CHANNEL_TOPIC );
        }, 1L, ALIVE_PERIOD, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
        
        // Receive node alive scheduler.
        CHECK_NODES_ALIVE_SCHEDULER = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        CHECK_NODES_ALIVE_SCHEDULER.scheduleAtFixedRate( ( ) -> {
            if ( getNodes().isEmpty() ) return;
            long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
            getNodes().forEach( node -> {
                try {
                    log.error( "SYS: Check node {}", node.getNodeId() );
                    
                    // Check if alive packet got in time
                    if ( current - lastAlive( node ) <= ALIVE_PERIOD + 500L ) return;
                    
                    // Fail
                    if ( addFail( node ) < CHECK_ALIVE_FAILS ) return;
                    
                    // Max fails reached > death
                    gotAlive( node ); // reset stats
                    nodeDeathConsumer.accept( node );
                } catch ( Exception e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } );
        }, 1L, ALIVE_PERIOD / 2L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
    }
    
    void addNode( Node node ) {
        gotAlive( node );
    }
    
    void removeNode( Node node ) {
        log.error( "SYS: Removed node {}", node.getNodeId() );
        ALIVE_PACKETS.remove( node );
        FAILS.remove( node );
        System.out.println( "1STILL NODES: " + ALIVE_PACKETS.keySet() );
    }
    
    void gotAlive( Node node ) {
        ALIVE_PACKETS.put( node, System.currentTimeMillis() );
        FAILS.put( node, 0 );
    }
    
    private int addFail( Node node ) {
        return FAILS.put( node, FAILS.get( node ) + 1 );
    }
    
    private long lastAlive( Node node ) {
        System.out.println( "2STILL NODES: " + ALIVE_PACKETS.keySet() );
        return ALIVE_PACKETS.get( node );
    }
    
    private Set<Node> getNodes( ) {
        System.out.println( "3STILL NODES: " + ALIVE_PACKETS.keySet() );
        return ALIVE_PACKETS.keySet();
    }
    
    private ClusterManager getClusterManager( ) {
        return ClusterManager.getInstance();
    }
    
    private RedworkManager getRedwork( ) {
        return getClusterManager().getRedwork();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void close( ) {
        SEND_NODE_ALIVE_SCHEDULER.shutdownNow();
        CHECK_NODES_ALIVE_SCHEDULER.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.mypvp.cloud.cluster.AliveSystem.lambda$null$1(AliveSystem.java:83)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at net.mypvp.cloud.cluster.AliveSystem.lambda$new$2(AliveSystem.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: ConcurrentMap doesn't make your code magically thread safe. You need to use atomic methods like `putIfAbsent` or else use another level of locking or synchronization.

Comment: Can you put an example?

Comment: what do you mean with atomic methods?

Comment: Given your comments, I get the sense that there's a lot about concurrency that you don't understand. It's hard to know how much to explain, but I suspect it would need to be much more than one answer here could contain. I would recommend the book *Java Concurrency in Practice* by Goetz et al as a good place to start.

Comment: What is on line 83?

Comment: return ALIVE_PACKETS.get( node ); // in lastAlive() method

Comment: Thanks to @DanielPryden pushing me in the right way!
I've found https://dzone.com/articles/concurrenthashmap-isnt-always-enough